# Integer, perfect divisors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I am trying to find a way of solving the following equation without using brute force on a computer.

I am looking for all $k \in N$ such that the expression given is an integer, $\frac{214-3k}{3+2k}$

The answer is k = 8, but I was hoping someone could point me to a smarter method?

Comment: it is most certainly not an equation, you probably meant "all $k \in \mathbb N$ such that the expression given is an integer"
but then again, $k=8$ is not a solution

Comment: $k=8$ doesn't work. The numerator is $190$ and the denominator is $21$, and $21$ does not divide $190$.

Comment: Yes, you are both correct, the divisor should be $3 +2k$. I have amended it.

Comment: Hello windircurse, yes the question should read as you have stated. I have also made this amend to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite as : $x=\frac{214-3k}{5+2k} = \frac{443}{2(2k+5)} - \frac{3}{2}$. Then, $\frac{443}{2k+5}=2x+3$, so $\frac{443}{2k+5}$ should be an integer. Turns out that $443$ is prime, hence $2k+5=\pm 1, \pm 443$, giving $k =  -2,-3,219,-224$. For these values,

$k=-2 \implies x = 220$.

$k = -3 \implies x = -223$.

$k=219 \implies x = -1$.

$k=-224 \implies x = -2$.

These are the only integer values of the expression.

---

EDIT : In here, I'll try to fill in the details of the first comment below.

In general, suppose that you have $\frac{ak+b}{ck+d}$. The way  to convert this to a "nice" decomposition, just do the following:

1) First separate it: $\frac{ak+b}{ck+d} = \frac{ak}{ck+d} + \frac{b}{ck+d}$.

2) Add the fraction $\dfrac{\frac{ad}{c}}{ck+d}$ , and subtract it as well:
$$
\frac{ak}{ck+d} + \frac{b}{ck+d} = \frac{ak+\frac{ad}{c}}{ck+d} + \frac{b - \frac{ad}{c}}{ck+d}
$$
Now, note that:
$$
\frac{ak+\frac{ad}{c}}{ck+d} = \frac{(ck+d)(\frac{a}{c})}{ck+d} = \frac{a}{c}
$$

And now your fraction is written as:
$$
\frac{a}{c} + \frac{b - \frac{ad}{c}}{ck+d}
$$

Which is the way we want it: there is only one $k$, and that is in the denominator.

Now you say you have changed $2k+5$ to $2k+3$. The equation will thus have changed, and I will show it.

Our original fraction is now $\frac{214-3k}{3+2k}$. Under our transformation, $a=-3,b=214,c=2,d=3$ , this becomes $\frac{-3}{2} + \frac{214 - \frac{(-3)(3)}{2}}{2k+3}$,which simplifies to $\frac{437}{2(2k+3)} - \frac{3}{2}$.

Let $x= \frac{437}{2(2k+3)} - \frac{3}{2}$, then $2x+3 = \frac{437}{2k+3}$. Hence $(2k+3)$ divides $437=19*23$. Hence, one of the following must happen:

$2k+3 = 1 \implies k = -1 \implies x = 217$.

$2k+3 = 19 \implies k = 8 \implies x = 10$.

$2k+3 = 23 \implies k = 10 \implies x = 8$.

$2k+3 = 437 \implies k = 217 \implies x = -1$

These are all the possibilities.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for replying so quickly. Could you please explain to me how you changed $\frac{214-3k}{5+2k}$ to $\frac{443}{2(2k+5)}-\frac{3}{2}$. Also, now that I have corrected the denominator will the same method work for $3+2k$?

Comment: @WD367217 I have kept the original answer intact, everything else has  been added to the answer.

Comment: That's fantastic. Thank you for making it so clear. Please could you let me know if this is something I would learn in an algebra book or if it is more number theory.

Comment: @WD367217 I learned this in sixth grade , and I literally had to invent it to solve these kind of problems. These are elementary transformations, not discussed in much detail either in number theory or in algebra, and handling and using them only comes with practice.